# Generating the same ARMA(1,1) sequence with different parameters

Tags: arima, arma

If I have two ARMA(1,1) processes with different sets of parameters, then what are the conditions so that I can get indistinguishable ARMA(1,1) sequences?

Comment: This could perhaps happen in cases where the AR and the MA roots cancel out or in other similarly nasty cases. I don't think this could happen in "nice" ARMA(1,1) models.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I have read somewhere that If two processes with different parameters have the same auto covariance function, they are the same process. I know it's true for MA process. But is it true for ARMA(1,1) process?

Comment: Could you include a concrete example for MA?